# How to prepare and structure data for multivariate time series forecasting?

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

I have multiple variables (x) that I want to use to be able to forecast multiple (y) that occur at the same time (t). I've provided a very basic outline below. In doing so, my requirement is to determine an overall relationship (if any) of how (x's) influence (y).

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4
```

t0  y1
t0  y2
t0  y3
t0  y4
t1  y1
t1  y2
t1  y3
t1  y4

The data consists of time periods = ~100, y's per time period = ~300 and variables for each y ie x = 4.

I'm struggling to see if there is a simpler way to deal with the regression problem (perhaps indexing y's for each time period?). Or is there a standard way of dealing with such a forecasting/regression problem that someone may be able to refer me to? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.